# Python idiomatic unpacking assignment or False

Tags: python, iterable-unpacking

If function returns a two value list or tuple on success or False on failure, how can I best unpack the return list into two variables while also checking for False?

```
def get_key_value():
  if (cond != True):
    return False
  return [val1, val2]

# Call it
# How can I also check for False while unpacking?
key, value = get_key_value()
```

Comment: Maybe it would be better to throw an exception instead of returning two different kinds of values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Coverting @Felix Kling's great comment into an answer.

If not being able to find a (key, value) pair indicates some kind of system failure, it would be better to throw an exception. If your failure doesn't really fall into any of the [standard exceptions](http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html), you should build a new exception type of your own.

The `cond != True` is better written as `not cond`. Also it's better to not create a list if it's not necessary.

```
class DataNotFound(Exception): pass

def get_key_value():
  if not cond:
    raise DataNotFound("Couldn't find it!")
  return val1, val2

try:
    key,value = get_key_value()
except DataNotFound:
    #handle the failure somehow
    key, value = 'ERROR', 'ERROR'
```

Comment: +1 Just two details: `if not cond:` and `return (val1, val2)`.

Comment: I agree with @delnan, `if not cond` is MUCH preferred over `if cond != True`.  As for the return, even just `return val1, val2` will suffice.

Answer (score 3):

This falls under the ["Easier to Ask for Forgiveness than Permission"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_syntax_and_semantics#Exceptions) policy of Python. I avoid catching TypeError in your function, in case there's some other unforeseen problem.

```
data = get_key_value()
try:
   key, value = data
except TypeError:
   #handle the failure somehow
   key, value = 'ERROR', 'ERROR'
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there *is* an idiomatic way to do this -- not least because a function that behaves that way is itself unidiomatic. If you have to do it, I suggest you simply make use of the fact that your 2-element list or tuple is a "truthy" rather than a "falsy" value (this isn't Python terminology but it's useful):

```
pair_or_false = get_key_value()
if pair:
    key,value = val
else:
    # handle failure in whatever way
```

The obvious alternative is to treat the not-found case as an exception:

```
try:
    key,value = get_key_value()
except TypeError:
    # deal with not-found case
```

but if there's any possibility at all that something other than the unsuccessful unpacking could raise a TypeError then you run the risk of masking a genuine error that way.

Comment: I had been dealing with it using your first `if/else` method but hoped to reduce my linecount since the function is called many times.  I'll see how it works out catching `TypeError`. The application is fairly straightforward DOM parsing and the risk is low for other `TypeErrors`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're running into problems because you're mixing return types. Just because you can doesn't mean you should.

Although I agree with the others here that an exception is one appropriate way to go, it may depend on whether you expect to find a valid key & value most of the time. If so, use an exception (something like `KeyError`) to indicate that the function failed. But if you expect it to fail at a high rate, you may not want the exception overhead. In that case, return something like `[None, None]` from `get_key_value` and then your calling code would look like:

```
key, value = get_key_value()
if key:
    # take action
else:
    # handle the error appropriately
```